# I try to parent an mesh to an armature but it shows up as a ghost child

Tags: armature, parent

i'm trying to set clothes onto a model, and parenting them to the armature but when i do, this "ghost parent" appears. and when i put it to an fbx, and bring it over to unity, it does not show up on the armature at all.

[image: ghost parenting??]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why its greyed out is because the the parent and the child are not in the same collection. So if you select the greyed out child and press M to and move it to the collection containing the parent object it wont be greyed out anymore.

Comment: thank you! this helped a lot!